# Delete from all tables where ip equals that ip

Tags: php, mysql

I have a lot of tables in my SQL database, and I want to delete from all tables from it where the IP matches a certain IP in one statement/Query. Is there a way to do it quickly?

Something like:

```
DELETE FROM * tables where ip = '$ip';
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: sounds like a design problem of your tables. maybe it would be better to change that

Comment: There's no automatic way to process all tables at once. You can get a list of tables from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and write a loop that generates a `DELETE` query for each of them.

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
$tables = ['table1','table2','table3'];

foreach($tables as $table){
  //DELETE FROM `$table` tables where ip = :ip;
}
```

Just make absolutely certain you are using prepared statements, and "canned" table names.  Never concatenate user input into your sql.

Imagine this `$ip = "1' OR 1=1";` Now all your data has been deleted.  AKA sql Injection.

Because your innocent query:

```
 DELETE FROM table where ip = '$ip'
```

Becomes:

```
  DELETE FROM table where ip = '1' OR 1=1
```

AND `1` is always equal to `1`

If you can't see the data your putting in when you look at the query, use prepared statements.  Because, you never know when you will re-purpose a piece of code and if it's not done right from the get go, your setting yourself up for a lot of headaches.

This may be a one time thing you are doing, but if you plan to leave the code around, I would still use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just separate them by a semicolon?

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id = 1;
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id = 1;
DELETE FROM table3 WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: Most PHP MySQL APIs don't allow multiple queries. The only one is `mysqli` when you use `mysqli_multi_query()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the details of the question that you have provided. You can do this with the help of Dynamic SQL.

Step 1) With the help of information_schema, prepare the dynamic SQL to delete the record from the table. You will get dynamic SQL like below

Delete from table1 where ColumnName = 'IPAddress';
Delete from table2 where ColumnName = 'IPAddress';

Step 2) With the help of Execute Statement. Run that dynamic SQL and this will delete all the records from those tables where the record has IP address in that column.

Comment: Won´t help MySQL´s PREPARE function can´t prepare multiple SQL statements.. `PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT 1; SELECT 2';` will result in a error. `Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT 2' at line 1`.. this error is telling me PREPARE can only handle one SQL statement.